# Grammar point for "listened to it tick"

Tags: grammar

> I wound up the watch and ***listened to it tick***.

I saw the sentence in the dictionary in my cellphone. I don't understand the grammar of the phrase "listened to it tick". It sounds natural to my non-native ear, but it doesn't seem to be grammatically correct when I thought it over. I think 'to' is a prep, 'it' a pronoun and 'tick' a verb. So, I can't see how it makes grammatical sense.

How should we understand it grammatically?

Comment: There's nothing particularly unusual about using a verb form there.  For example, "I saw them swim."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting! "listened to it tick," is commonly used colloquial English, but grammatically, it might be thought of as, "listened to *its* tick." In defense of this (or defence, if you're learning UK English), consider the following:

1. "Listen to her whisper."
2. "Listen to his heartbeat."
3. "Listen to its growl."
4. "Listen to it growl."

All four are valid, and the first three examples use the possessive pronoun.

However, the fourth example calls attention to the *referent*, perhaps an animal, while the third calls attention to the *sound*. It might also be though of as, "Listen to it [as it] growl[s]."

Comment: Oe 'Listen to it _ticking_'.

Comment: I'm not sure why this sentence has to be thought of as anything else.  Why can't you listen to (a verb form)?  No one would blink at, for example, "I saw them run."